# S3 and Paperclip with Heroku for a Rails app - migrations not running on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, migration, paperclip

I set up an app to upload pictures directly to s3 for the `User` class.  Locally, all is working fine.  I added an attribute to the user class called `avatar`.  In the rails console, when I call `User.last.avatar.url` I get the S3 url for the picture that was uploaded.

When I pushed my changes to Heroku, though, I tried running migrations but nothing happened, and obviously, in the Heroku console, I get a method error when I run `User.last.avatar.url`

Not sure what to do or what happened. I only have one bucket but I don't think that's why the migrations aren't running.

EDIT : here's the migration

```
    class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more info please? Perhaps your migration file...also, to access your Heroku DB you can run `heroku run rails console`. From there, check to see if those columns generated by Paperclip are on the user class by just typing in the class name - `User`.

Comment: I know those columns weren't generated by the migrations, as nothing happens when I run the Heroku migrations

Comment: Alright two things come to mind. 1) did you make sure you committed those changes prior to pushing your repo to Heroku? 2) how did you run the heroku db migration?